# .htaccess 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

Does anyone know how can I do a 301 redirect traffic from one domain to the other - including all the same url elements after domain name - and apply the same rule to all possible links without writing it for each url separately - example would be something like this:

```
http://www.olddomain.com/catalogue/category/fruits/pg/2.html
```

to redirect to:

```
http://www.newdomain.com/catalogue/category/fruits/pg/2.html
```

At the moment I have something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.newdomain\.com" [R=301,L]
```

but this won't work for the following situation for instance:

```
http://www.olddomain.com/login.html
```

it simply won't redirect to the new domain and keep the /login.html after.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried simply:

```
Redirect 301 / http://newdomain.com/
```

In the root folder of olddomain.com

Answer (score 1):

Youre RewriteRule is incorrect. You're only redirecting http://www.olddomain.com/ but not /login.html

Try modifying the rewrite rule to include all paths on the old domain:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: yes - but this one is not going to redirect me to 'http://www.newdomain.com/login.html' - it will redirect me directly to 'http://www.newdomain.com' if I type 'http://www.olddomain.com/login.html' - so not really what I'm looking for

Comment: @user398341 You missed the $1 at the end. (.*) captures the path at the old domain and I refer to that using $1 in the redirect. So it should redirect olddomain.com/login.html to newdomain.com/login.html

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any difference I'm afraid.

Comment: It appears we were missing forward slash after '.com'

Answer (score 0):

Ok - after a lot of googling I've found the solution - which comes to a simple two lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.newdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks everyone for participating.